# Expresso Store Order Submission Validation Error Not Defining Which Field

Tags: expresso-store, forms, expresso, payment-gateway

EE 5.3.0

I have a cart with a checkout page. When I try to submit a test order using the dummy processor I'm getting this result

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors
- This field is required.
Return to Previous Page
```

In other words it's not specifying which field has the error so I don't know how I'm supposed to know what to fix. I previously had `error_handling=”inline”` in the tag with a series of `{error:field_name}` tags at the top of the form. That resulted in nothing so I removed the parameter and now it goes to the ugly built-in EE error page.

This is the first expresso store I've set up and I'm sure I'm leaving something out, but if anyone has any advice I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Great working with you via our support email. Still working on the second half with the field name, but wanted to note here that the quote marks for the error handling need to be regular quotes, `"` vs of `”`, in case anyone else is running into the same issue.

Comment: Howdy. I've been reaching out to you this week and haven't heard back. After changing the form based on the guidance you gave me, user information has begun validating but now payments will not process and transactions cannot be completed. I think it's because of issues validating `payment_method`, but I need more help with it. If you get a chance please respond to me either here or via email.